# 500 Gateway with EC2 m5.2xlarge

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, performance, php.ini

I have an EC2 m5.2xlarge

with wordpress and the following server configuration:

https://pasteboard.co/JwP5Ecg.png

How is possible to receive a 500 Gateway Error for importing a csv with 50 users (45 is working)?

It seems the error appears after one minute even if I change php.ini configuration.

Any tips?

P.S. how big is the change moving the mysql DB to Aurora?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check your logs.

Comment: You're right man..chekcing this for now :) https://serverfault.com/questions/775855/how-to-configure-apache-workers-for-maximum-concurrency